# Looking for a book set in a binary solar system

Tags: story-identification, novel, good-against-evil

I read a book many years ago, the details are sketchy and I have searched the internet for the last 2 years trying to find this book, but it eludes me. Hopefully someone on here will have read it too.

Here are the details as I remember:

The book is set in a binary solar system.
The entities or creatures on the planets orbiting the stars are re-animated beings (humans and others?) that have long since died.
The one star is called Sol. One is dark and one is light. Turns out the stars are in fact super computers and brothers (don't ask me how).

There is a battle between light and dark, good and evil.

The plot twist is

> While the light/good side is fighting to defeat the evil/dark side, it turns out that the light side is corrupt and doesn't even know it, and the evil they are trying to fight is actually good.

That really is all I remember. I cannot remember the title name or author.

Comment: Sounds like a story based off the Nemesis Theory?

Comment: No, not the Nemesis Theory. Basically the binary system is a projection from another dimension into ours. The stars are sentient computers.

Comment: Hi Dave! Did you ever get the chance to check out if the _Last legends of Earth_ book was the one you were looking for? If so, could you accept the answer below? Keeps stuff organized :)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207087/space-war-humans-recreated-grown-from-plants-with-an-alien-female-supervisor

Answer (score 2):

The book you are looking for is the [Last Legends of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Legends_of_Earth) by [A.A. Attanasio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._A._Attanasio) which is the final book in the [Radix Tetrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_Tetrad).

Gai, a Rimstalker, is sent to our universe to set a trap for the arachnid aliens known as the zotl.  The heart of this trap was a binary star system with fifteen planets.  There were computers at the heart of each star:  the light Lod and the dark Saor.  Lod and Saor are often referred to as brothers in the novel.

As bait for the trap, humans were resurrected using "radio" signals from DNA.

> Throughout the novel Lod is portrayed as supporting Gai's mission and Saor is opposing.  However, Lod was corrupted by the zotl to disrupt the trap.

Comment: No sorry, although this book does look awesome.  I remember that it was a binary system with a sun and a black star, which were both projections of higher-order machines from another dimension.

Comment: @DaveThompson seriously, Last Legends of Earth. Lod and Saor form a binary system, one is a star, one is a black hole. Plot twist which is your plot twist. Reanimated humans. The lot.

Comment: Dude, I am going to read these books now and confirm. I did read it in 97 so it's been awhile. Thank you